# How to get maven to use a different JAXB library to one in JDK

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

I'm using java 1.6.0_14 which includes an implementation of the annotation `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement`. However the one in the JDK only applies to Method and Field.

I've found jaxb-api.jar version 2.2.3 permits this on Parameter too, so I want to use this version.

Problem is, I can't figure out how to get maven to use this one in preference to the one in the JDK so that when I am writing my code it doesn't complain that the annotation is being used in an invalid location.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should be able to put jaxb-api.jar ahead in the classpath by explicitly adding dependency to it in your pom. And if you are not using maven to run application then you have to make sure that new library is available in the classpath before old one.

Comment: Have you tried Java 6 update 27? (Update 14 is pretty old)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey. Thanks for that, but Java 6 javadoc for xmlelement shows it's only for FIELD and METHOD. Java 7, on the other hand, allows it on PARAMETER too - but I can't justify upgrading to v7 to get round this problem.

Comment: Sorry, the latest Java 6 is update 29. You could add the library to the `jre/lib/endorsed` directory (which you have to add). Anything in this directory is used in preference to what is in the JRE. (Even java.lang.Object if you wish ;)

Comment: @Peter I've outlined in the answer Nicola gave that the endorsed directory works but that we've decided to abandon this for the time being and wait until we upgrade java on our project. Thanks all the same.

Comment: @DaveRlz, I am using Java 7 update 1 now. If this is an option, its likely to be the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include an explicit dependency in your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not the problem - the jar is in my maven dependencies (I can see it) but the order it appears in the classpath is the issue. So, in eclipse I can reorder the jar and the JDK (project > properties > java build path > order and export tab) and things work - but how do I do this with maven?

Comment: I'm baffled. We're using jaxb-api 2.1 explicitly, but I don't think we're doing anything special apart from adding it to our POM's. The other jaxb related setting we do have is for the maven-jaxb-plugin, but that should only be relevant for code generation, I would say.

Comment: Nope, still finds the JDK one first no matter where I put my dependency - are you using java 1.6? I found someone else ([link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654628/maven-build-of-annotated-jaxb-2-2-4-1-web-service-fails-with-jdk-1-6[/link]) has had a similar problem and their workaround was to add to the compiler buildpath. This gets round the problem (the command line build now completes) but doesn't feel right and anyway eclipse still doesn't know about the dependency ordering.

Comment: I am using Java 1.6 indeed. I have the compiler plugin explicitly configured to enforce 1.6 as both source and target version. One thing you could try is to exploit the [`endorsed`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) mechanism to force recognition of your version of jaxb-api.

Comment: Thanks for this. I copied the jar into the endorsed directory and this does resolve the problem, eclipse picks it up and all looks good...however, we've decided against doing things this way (management issue, and we'd have to manually copy that new jar everywhere including build servers etc) and wait until we upgrade to java 7, whenever that is.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the Java endorsed override mechanism.  I got this directly from the Apache CXF website.

JAXB is the default data binding for CXF. If you don't specify one of the other data bindings in your Spring configuration or through the API, you will get JAXB. Releases of CXF since 2.3.x have used the JDK7 default of JAXB 2.2, however Maven users running on JDK 6 will need to use the Java endorsed override mechanism to use JAXB 2.2 instead of JAXB 2.1.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxb.html  first paragraph at the top.  You basically download the new version of jaxb then tell the JRE/JDK to load that instead of the default implementation that it shipped with.