# javax.xml.bind not working in Android Studio(Gradle)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-gradle-plugin

I recently migrated my android project from maven to gradle. After doing so, I'm unable to **import javax.xml.bind** in my java file. This was working well when the project was in maven(probably because it was a java project and not an android project).

I searched on net and found out that JVM supports **javax.xml.bind** but DVM(Dalvik Virtual Machine) doesn't. So I tried adding this library as a dependency in my **build.gradle** file as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.x'
    ....
}
```

When I build my app after the above change I get the following build error:

```
:dexDebug
Unknown source file : trouble processing "javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.class":
Unknown source file : Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Unknown source file : when not building a core library.
Unknown source file : This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Unknown source file : in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Unknown source file : Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Unknown source file : core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Unknown source file : going on.
Unknown source file : However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Unknown source file : namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Unknown source file : from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Unknown source file : assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Unknown source file : compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Unknown source file : It is also often of questionable legality.
Unknown source file : If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Unknown source file : appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Unknown source file : distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Unknown source file : the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Unknown source file : If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Unknown source file : building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Unknown source file : will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Unknown source file : prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Unknown source file : application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Unknown source file : system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Unknown source file : If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Unknown source file : core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Unknown source file : repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Unknown source file : your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Unknown source file : conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Unknown source file : you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Unknown source file : that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Unknown source file : lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Unknown source file : 1 error; aborting

:dexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

How can I import this library successfully? I'm a beginner in android and gradle so any help will be of great use for me :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838675/how-to-get-maven-to-use-a-different-jaxb-library-to-one-in-jdk

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The above link is maven specific but we are using gradle. Also, this is an android project so it's under DVM.

Comment: okay set `2.2.9` instead of `2.2.x`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya still the same error

Answer (score 0):

It seen that your project is importing a core class (java.* or javax.*).

Here is a way that you can use "JarJar" tool to change "javax.xml.bind" namespace to another (Ex:"oop.xml.bind"), so you can resolve this problem and import it as Third-Party library , that you can avoid the same namespace with core class.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 xjc 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.x'
```